# Is it possible to run classic asp on Cassini Webserver?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, cassini

Is it possible to run classic asp on Cassini Webserver?

I have a mixed website (classic asp and dotnet)...

Comment: Why do you want to use Cassini?  I do all my web development through IIS regardless since it performs much better.

Comment: @Kirk, having to run Visual Studio is a pain, plus the faff of mapping a virtual directory to the project folder. It's just not as *zero friction* as using Cassini. Plus, I've never found a situation where I need "better performance" during development from my web server! =)

Comment: 1) What do you mean "having to run Visual Studio is a pain"?  What does IIS have to do with VS?  2) It takes about 10 seconds to set the site up in IIS.  3) In Cassini, I find refreshing web pages often takes on the order of a second or two, rather than the millisecond responses that IIS delivers.  Call me impatient. :)

Comment: @Kirk, Ooops, typo from me - I meant having to run VS as Administrator (at least on Vista/Win7) to allow it to communicate with IIS; either way IISExpress makes the limitations of both Full IIS & Cassini disappear, which is a clear winner for me =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. Cassini only renders ASP.net pages.

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)? It's similar to Sql Server Express user instances in that it can be run and used without requiring administrative privileges or changes to your code to cater for it. It's a "user mode" version of IIS, and thus fully supports Classic ASP which would help with your scenario.

It's not integrated into Visual Studio (in the same way Cassini is) yet, but there'll be a tooling patch to do that at some point.

Comment: @Kirk, There are a few things that *don't* work in Cassini (but do work in IIS) that can be worked around by using different techniques so they work in both, which makes it easier sometimes to code to Cassini's limitations. I can't remember what they are off the top of my head, but there are a few of them

Comment: Eduardo really answered my question, but I upvoted your answer thanks to the IIS Express tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Cassini is run from within Visual Studio. If you have a solution that contains both ASP.NET and ASP, it will continue to run on Cassini. But you can not run a pure classic ASP application this way.

Comment: Yeap, but classic asp pages do not render on cassini :(

Comment: You can also run Cassini from the command prompt http://blog.krisvandermast.com/HowToRunningTheBuiltInWebserverOfVisualStudio2005Yourself.aspx