# How can I run a classic asp site (not asp.net) from within VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp-classic

I am just putting together a quick non-cms site. Even though it's non-cms I would still like to use includes with it. Is there an easy way for me to run a classic ASP file in VS2010 without having to install/configure IIS?

Comment: No: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505362/is-it-possible-to-run-classic-asp-on-cassini-webserver

Comment: As mentioned in the post I linked, you can try IIS Express which has a lot smaller footprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a new web site project and configure it to use IIS Express. I added the .asp files to the project and it served them correctly.